# ¿Seria posible esta consulta SQL?

Tags: php, sql

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO USUARIOS (partidas,partidas_ganas,turnos) 
    VALUES ((select partidas FROM usuarios WHERE nombre like='$nombre') + 1,
        (SELECT partidas_perdidas FROM usuarios WHERE nombre LIKE = '$nombre') + 1)";
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Si se puede por que usas sub-consultas solo tienes que armar bien tu consulta si vas a insertar tres datos debes mandarle los tres datos. por ejemplo:

Supongamos que tenemos una tabla llamada repres con la misma estructura que la tabla empleados, y queremos insertar en esa tabla los empleados que tengan como titulo **rep ventas**

```
INSERT INTO repres SELECT * FROM empleados WHERE titulo = 'rep ventas'
```

Con la **SELECT** obtenemos las filas correspondientes a los empleados con título **rep ventas**,y las insertamos en la tabla **repres**. Como las tablas tienen la misma estructura no hace falta poner la lista de columnas y podemos emplear * en la lista de selección de la **SELECT**.

Supongamos ahora que la tabla **repres** tuviese las siguientes columnas **numemp**, **oficinarep**, **nombrerep**. En este caso no podríamos utilizar el asterisco, tendríamos que poner:

```
INSERT INTO repres SELECT numemp, oficina, nombre FROM empleados WHERE titulo = 'rep ventas'
```

O bien:

```
INSERT INTO repres (numemp, oficinarep, nombrerep) SELECT numemp, oficina, nombre FROM empleados WHERE titulo = 'rep ventas'
```

Answer (score 0):

Es posible la inserción de datos mediante esas subconsultas. Pero si te fijas en el **VALUES** solo estas insertando 2 de las 3 columnas, **partidas** y **partidas_ganadas**, dejando fuera a **turnos** por lo que no te dejará realizar el insert. Para compensar esto, si es que no va un valor, utiliza un 0.

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO USUARIOS (partidas,partidas_ganas,turnos) 
        VALUES ((select partidas FROM usuarios WHERE nombre like='$nombre') + 1,
        (SELECT partidas_perdidas FROM usuarios WHERE nombre LIKE = '$nombre') + 1), 0";
```

Espero te sirva mi respuesta, saludos.

Answer (score 0):

Puedes usar un insert into select , 'turnos' desconozco su valor

```
"INSERT INTO USUARIOS (partidas,partidas_ganas,turnos) SELECT partidas+1,partidas_perdidas+1,turnos FROM usuarios WHERE nombre like='$nombre'"
```